Creating an Independent Copy of a Nested Map with Dynamic Data in Flutter-Dart?
In my Flutter-Dart project, I have a map (myMap) that contains nested lists and maps, and these nested structures can further contain lists or maps. The data within these structures is dynamic, originating from a server, making it challenging to anticipate their lengths or values. An illustrative example of myMap is as follows:
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
  'key': {
    'key': [1, 2, 3],
    'key2': {
      'key': 23,
      'subKey': {
        'nestedKey': [
          4,
          5,
          {
            'deepKey': {
              'finalList': [
                9,
                10,
                {
                  'ultraKey': [11, 12]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  'key2': {
    'key': [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      {
        'dsf': [
          1,
          2,
          {
            'superKey': [
              3,
              4,
              {
                'megaKey': [5, 6]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    'key2': {
      'key': 23,
      'fdasd': [
        {
          'nestedList': [
            7,
            8,
            {
              'deepKey': {
                'finalList': [
                  9,
                  10,
                  {
                    'ultraKey': [
                      11,
                      12,
                      {
                        'ultimateKey': [13, 14]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

Now, I need to create another map (myMap2) = (myMap ) that is entirely independent of myMap. Merely assigning myMap2 = myMap creates a reference, leading to changes in one affecting the other. Similarly, using Map.of(myMap) doesn't achieve independence for nested lists and maps; modifications to nested structures in myMap reflect in myMap2.
I am currently using a manual approach involving looping through myMap and conditionally copying lists or maps using List.of() or Map.of(). However, this solution is not optimal due to the dynamic and unpredictable nature of the data received from the server.
manual (maybe it need improvement)
Map deepCopy(Map original) {
  Map copy = {};
  original.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      copy[key] = Map.of(deepCopy(value));
    } else if (value is List) {
      copy[key] = List.of(deepCopy2(value));
    } else {
      copy[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return copy;
}

List deepCopy2(List original) {
  List copy = [];
  for (var value in original) {
    if (value is Map) {
      copy.add(Map.of(deepCopy(value)));
    } else if (value is List) {
      copy.add(List.of(deepCopy2(value)));
    } else {
      copy.add(value);
    }
  }
  return copy;
}

Map myMap2 = deepCopy(myMap);

Is there a concise and efficient one-liner or method that ensures complete independence for all items, including nested structures within myMap and those within them?
the answer of my question might be using jsonDecode(jsonEncode(data)) but this make me worry for some unsupported types so i need always take care a lot of it's property toEncodable.

What do you mean by 'currently I am using a manual approach'? Do you use a function that recursively creates copies of all nested maps, lists, etc?

@DanR EXACTLY ...

Maybe you could include this function with your post and others could comment if it can be improved. Also, you mentioned that the data originates from a server. Do you have to validate and decode the incoming data?

https://pub.dev/packages/deepcopy may be useful

I am not aware of any simple approach to automatically generate a deep copy of arbitrary objects or collections of objects.
However, the functions you have posted can be improved. For clarity, I named the optimized functions deepCopyMap and deepCopyList. Within the recursive call to deepCopyMap there is no need to use Map.of() since you already create a new map (with local name copy). The same applies to the function deepCopyList.
These changes alone almost half the execution time:
deepCopy(myMap) mean: 5.77 ± 2.38 us

deepCopyMap(myMap) mean: 3.33 ± 0.86 us
            

Map deepCopyMap(Map original) {
  Map copy = {};
  original.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      copy[key] = deepCopyMap(value);
    } else if (value is List) {
      copy[key] = deepCopyList(value);
    } else {
      copy[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return copy;
}

List deepCopyList(List original) {
  List copy = [];
  for (var value in original) {
    if (value is Map) {
      copy.add(deepCopyMap(value));
    } else if (value is List) {
      copy.add(deepCopyList(value));
    } else {
      copy.add(value);
    }
  }
  return copy;
}


Can even inline the literals, and have only one function: Object? clone(Object? value) => switch (value) {Map map => {for (var MapEntry(:key, :value) in map.entries) key: clone(value)}, List list => [for (var value in list) clone(value)], _ => value};.  (Not a lot of formatting in a comment.)

@lrn That's pretty concise. And the switch statement can be easily extended to handle other cases. Maybe consider posting this as an answer?
